# Unix - Expect Shell - Syntax for using ifcondition on while loop

Tags: shell-script, aix, expect

I have been working on a expect script on AIX OS. The script should pick the server list from input file from while loop and proceed with an if condition to match a specific pattern then proceed. else proceed with else if and proceed with next steps.

Unfortunately the script doesn't provide any output. Doesn't report any error or print nothing

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 15
#exp_internal 1
set ip_file "host.txt"
set fid [open $ip_file r]
while {[gets $fid ip] != -1} {
      if  {[regexp  \[AU*N\]\[Z\]\[1\]\[7\]\+ $ip]} {
           puts "Server Belongs to APC"  
           spawn ssh -J lauk576 padmin@$ip;
           expect "Password:";
           send "Helloworld123\n";
           expect "$";
           send "oem_setup_env\n";
           expect "#";
           send {lsmcode -A | sed -e "s/^/$(uname -n): /"};
           send "\n";
           expect "#";
           send "exit\n";
           expect "$";
           send "exit\n" ;
           expect eof
      } elseif {[regexp  \[EMEA*LC\]\[T\]\+ $ip]} {
                puts "Server Belongs to EMEA "  
                           expect eof
         }

 }         
close $fid
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the host file so we can verify your regular expressions.

Comment: You should also show (a few sample lines of) your input file `host.txt`.

Comment: The only obvious thing I see is the `expect eof` in the elseif block: you haven't spawned anything there.

Comment: Host.txt file.  AU345NZ17 EMEA753LCT AU7654NZ18

Comment: Host.txt is a file containing server names on each line..

Comment: Tried removing eof on the elseif still no luck..

Comment: The same process without using if statement works. The reason for using if statement is for different hosts I need jump different jump server and SSH the target host

Comment: You are not using the right regexp pattern. To match `AU345NZ17` for example you would need something like `regexp {AU.*NZ17} $ip` (I've used `{}` instead of needing to use backslash so often). The actual pattern depends on what variety of names you want to match.

Comment: @meuh  thanks a lot for the timely help. I think the issue is on the regular expression.  I have a if condition in bash like below. Would you be able to provide the regular expression for the same that can be used on Expect Shell  if [[ $ip == AU[357]NZ[1789] ]] then a print a value.

Comment: @meuh the regular expression you provided fixed the if condition and it has proceeded. But the while loop doesnt execute the next host in the file. The script gets complete without executing the next server list.. any thoughts ?

Comment: The bash condition `AU[357]NZ[1789]` is a glob pattern. The `expect` regexp equivalent (using `{}` to quote the string) is `{AU[357]NZ[1789]}` which is almost the same because it is a simple example. You can get `expect` to print each line before it is executed by adding the line `strace 99` after the first line. The output prints the current depth of nesting. Or you can use the debugger by adding `debug 1`. At the prompt type `s` to step on. Use `h` for help.

Comment: @meuh Many thanks for the quick fix. Finally i was able to run the loop with the condition.